# How to make image in Bootstrap thumbnail square and responsive?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Currently I am using the bootstrap thumbnail. This code gets me exactly what I want, but only on the desktop view. Once I resize to mobile, it retains the 358x358 size as I specified so its not responsive.

Basically I want the thumbnail image to always be cropped to square regardless of the image file given to it. How do I make this responsive but keep the same square image aspect ratio? Thanks for your help.

```
.thumb-img{
   object-fit: cover;
   overflow: hidden;
   height: 358px; 
   width : 358px;
}
```

and I'm using it like this

```
<div class="thumbnail">
      <img class="thumb-img" src="66-Yacht-582x357.jpg" alt="yacht" />
</div>
```

Comment: That seems to work for me... it scales down and is a square in mobile http://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/aWzRwV

Comment: further, bootstrap applies `max-width: 100%` to `.thumbnail > img` which is what makes it responsive.

Answer (score 1):

For responsive size you can use `vw` against `px`.
Like this:

```
.thumb-img{
   object-fit: cover;
   overflow: hidden;
   height: 30vh; 
   width : 30vw;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I'm using Bootstrap 4 and have the exact same issue as the user who posted the question. Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Try with providing height and width in "%" in responsive, it works for me.

```
.thumb-img {
    object-fit: cover;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 30%;
    width: 30%;
}
```